# Creating a array of mock object of a class A.class

Tags: java, android, mockito, powermock

Creating a array of mock object of a class A.class

I tried  Signature[] signature= PowerMockito.mock(Signature[].class);

Comment: Do you want to mock the array? If no, just create the array like you would create any ordinary array.

Comment: As i have mentioned i want to create an array mock object.
Suppose class is  Signature.class

Then i want to create Signature[] signature

Comment: And as _I_ have mentioned, then you just need to create an ordinary array. What is the problem with doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the array itself is not the testobject. Create Signature-mocks and add it to an array.

```
Signature sig = mock(Signature.class);
Signature[] signature = new Signature[]{sig};
```